# Enable unsafe sysctls on a cluster managed by Amazon EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, sysctl

I'm attempting to follow instructions for resolving a data congestion issue by enabling 2 unsafe sysctls for certain pods running in a Kubernetes cluster where the Pods are deployed by EKS. To do this, I must enable those parameters in the nodes running those pods. The following command is for enabling on a per-node basis:

```
kubelet --allowed-unsafe-sysctls \
  'net.unix.max_dgram_qlen,net.core.somaxconn'
```

However, the Nodes in the cluster I am working with are deployed by EKS. The EKS cluster was deployed by using the Amazon dashboard (Not a yaml config file/terraform/etc). I am not sure how to translate the above step to have all nodes in my cluster have those systcl enabled.

Comment: Have you seen this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68138789/enable-unsafe-sysctls-on-a-cluster-managed-by-amazon-eks?

Comment: That's a link to this question

Comment: Sorry for that, I must have pasted the wrong thing, I meant https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/184 and also https://itnext.io/of-kubernetes-unsafe-sysctls-performance-optimization-on-eks-d36cc0e3e894.

Comment: You need to use a custom bootstrap script in the launch template of your managed node group. I posted a more detailed answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/70346926/908257

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing DataDog agent congestion issues in Amazon EKS cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68092279/fixing-datadog-agent-congestion-issues-in-amazon-eks-cluster)